# If class that was clicked on has certain text, run jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a "menu" of elements which all have the same class. Looks like this:

```
<div id="menu">
   <div class="menu_item">
        first
   </div>
   <div class="menu_item">
        second
   </div>
```

How can I write jquery which basically goes like:

If class element that was clicked on contains "first" then do first option. Else if it contains "second" then do second option.

My Attempt:

```
$(".menu_item").click(function(){
    if(".menu_item:contains("first")"){
        $("#first_info").animate({opacity: 1,left: "50%" }, 'slow')
    }
```

Comment: You could use event delegation. Have you tried something?

Comment: could expand more what you want to do to each element when clicked

Comment: `if(".menu_item:contains("first")")` is quite an obvious syntax error.

Comment: I would like to "animate" a div upon clicking one of the items. Each item corresponds to a different div. So clicking the menu_item that has "first" should animate #first_info in. If it's second, it should animate #second_info in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add class to the menu item first element `first`, like this `<div class="menu_item first">`.

So in your JS, this explains, if `.menu_item` has class `first` then animate `#first_info` element then else do this...

```
  $("body").on('click', '.menu_item', function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('first')){
      $("#first_info").animate({opacity: 1, left: "50%" }, 'slow');
     } else{
      // do this
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you can do something like this.

```
$(".menu-item").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).attr("class");
    if (text.indexOf("first") != -1) {
        //do option 1
    };
    if (text.indexOf("second") != -1) {
        //do option 2
    };
})
```

You handle the click event. Inside that click event, you check for your element text. IndexOf is going to return -1 if none is found, or the position if found.

When you do your code like this, both option can be run, saying you have an element with class `first second`. If you don't want that, nest the if.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error at `if` condition.

1. Element catching error
2. Apostrophe error

You can use the syntax in the following code snippets. Here catching the `this` element and using the `is` method along with `contains` selector.

```js
$(".menu_item").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":contains('first')")) {  
    $("#first_info").animate({
      opacity: 1,
      left: "50%"
    }, 'slow')
  } else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu_item">
    first
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    second
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
        $(".menu_item").click(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf($(this).children().attr('id'))!== -1){
        $(this).children().fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
       }});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
       <div class="menu_item">
            first<div style="background:red" id="first_info" >first_info</div>
       </div>
       <div class="menu_item">
            second<div style="background:yellow" id="second_info" >second_info</div>
       </div>
```